# The usage of adjectives

Tags: adjectives

Please help with this.
I love also you. Wrong right?

I also love you. Correct right?

Also I love you. That's correct too? Do I need a comma after also?

Comment: Asking "is this correct" is off-topic here. Some suggestions to make it on-topic - have you done any research? Why do you think it is wrong? Why do you think it might be right? Can you explain your doubt?

Comment: Please look at your post and correct it. I have now corrected it for you. It does contain an interesting grammar point.

Comment: _Wrong right?_ doesn't mean anything. You should ask _This is wrong, isn't it?_

Comment: Voting to reopen: This was *not* a proofreading request, it was a question about how "also" changes meaning in syntax. Note: it can! Usually "also" applies to the word immediately before it. (But it doesn't always have to.) It can be left to the context to make it clear. "I love chocolate. I also love you." -> I love two things. "Bob loves you. I also love you." -> Two people love you. Meaning is determined by context.

Answer (score 2):

The first is not idiomatic. Don't use it.

The second could be used:

> I respect you. I fear you. But I also love you.

Or

> I love your sister, but I also love you.  What a dilemma!

Or

> Jack loves you, but I also love you.  You have to make a choice!

The third could be used indicate that "I love you" is an afterthought.  A comma is preferred.

> I'm not giving up on this marriage because of the kids.  Also, I love you! That must be worth something.